# How to redirect S3 hosted static site from Domain A to Domain B in AWS Cloudfront setup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

## My problem

I'm trying to 301 redirect my S3 hosted **domain-a.com** to **domain-b.com** in my SSL-secured AWS Cloudfront setup. I cannot figure out how to achieve this. Instead both domains now serve the Cloudfront/S3 Bucket content.

## My use case

Before switching to Cloudfront I used to handle redirects with S3's static website hosting options by redirecting the secondary domain bucket to the primary domain bucket.

In order to secure my S3-hosted static site with SSL certificates I made the switch to Cloudfront.

SSL certificates work fine, but because now both domains point to the cloudfront distribution (see screenshots below) I can access the same content on both domains. This does not only lead to duplicate content but also confuses users and is not really the best UX.

## Route 53 and Cloudfront config for both domains

- Route 53 points to a single Cloudfront distribution for **both** domain-a.com and domain-b.com
- Cloudfront points to the domain-b.com S3 bucket

[image: domain-a.com Route 53 configuration]
[image: domain-b.com Route 53 configuration]
[image: Cloudfront configuration]

How can I redirect domain-a.com to domain-b.com so as to only have one primary domain which my users see and use? Can this be achieved through Route 53 DNS settings or do I have to edit my Cloudfront configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate bucket for domain-a.com, configure that in your CloudFront and apply the redirect rules to point it to domain-b.com.

Check the picture below on how to set the redirect.

[image: Redirect all requests to domain-b.com]

Hope it helps.